# Should I use strong induction to solve the following problem? Am I on the right track?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove that for any positive integer n, the sum of
any distinct n odd positive integers greater than or equal to n^2.

My work so far:

Let S(n) = 1 + 3+ 5... (2n-1)

Base case:

$n=1$, $S(1) = 1^2 =1 $

Assume that $S(n) \geq n^2$ is true:

Prove that it is also true for (n+1)

Am I in the right track? Just making sure strong induction is the right way to solve this problem

Comment: Yes, although I'd be inclined to prove that the sum of *the first* $n$ positive odd integers is **equal to** $n^2$.  From there it's an easy step to prove that the sum  of *any* $n$ distinct positive odd integers must be **at least** $n^2$.  You don't need strong induction for this proof.

Comment: @coffeemath That is a typo. It should be 1

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're on the right track, and no you don't need strong induction. Also, I think you will be better off proving that $1+3+5+\cdots +2n-1=n^2$, which will imply the inequality you want as well. It will help to notice that the $kth$ odd number is $2k-1$ and the odd number after that is $2k+1$. So, if $P(n)$ is the proposition that the sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2$; i.e.

$$P(n): 1+3+5+\cdots +2n-1=n^2$$

you can suppose that $P(k)$ holds for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and add $2k+1$ to both sides of $P(k)$ to yield $P(k+1)$.